# Find the hidden formula with Tensorflow (Handling Numeric I/O)

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, neural-network, numeric

I have a standard CSV file with a bunch of rows that all have 60 columns of random numbers (float). On columns 61-63, I have numbers (floats again) that are some function of the first 60 columns.

I did the sum of the first 20 columns multiplied by the sum of the next 40 columns for the first “output” column and then other arbitrary variations for the next two output columns. I want my machine learning algorithm to pick up on this formulaic relationship and give predictions for the three output numbers.

Here is how I read in the data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def read_data():
    rd = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    x = rd[rd.columns[0:60]].values
    y = rd[rd.columns[60:63]].values
    X = x.astype(float) #just making sure we have the right dtype 
    Y = y.astype(float) 
    print(X.shape)
    print(Y.shape)
    return (X, Y)

X, Y = read_data()
```

Then I shuffle and split the data into training and testing sets

```
X, Y = shuffle(X, Y, random_state=1)
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=117)
```

Next I define my model, the weights and biases

```
n_dim = X.shape[1]
print("n_dim", n_dim)
n_output = Y.shape[1]
print("n_output", n_output)    
n_hidden_1 = 100
n_hidden_2 = 75
n_hidden_3 = 50
n_hidden_4 = 50
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_dim])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_dim, n_output]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_output]))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output])

def layered_model(x, weights, biases):

    # 4 hidden layers with sigmoid and relu
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['w1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['w2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)

    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['w3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_3)

    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['w4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

weights = {
    'w1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_dim, n_hidden_1])),
    'w2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'w3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3])),
    'w4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_4, n_output]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_3])),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_4])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_output]))
}
```

How do I feed my data into a cost function, and then use that for my epochs? All the tutorials I can find are for labeled datasets, putting things into "buckets". Whereas this is a purely numeric input/output.

The only information I can find is that numeric cost functions usually use a squared error approach and feed_dict will be necessary:

```
cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - actual))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it "working". However, the cost function gets minimized to a number that is close to all the training results and then it will always return that number, regardless of the input. Not really "learning" in the useful sense.

I found that I had to break my problem into a classification task before machine learning could make useful predictions.